# Filling in a zero for all empty time bins for each cluster (region) as part of an ambulance response/posting analysis

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, time-series, list-comprehension

I have a my data from an agencies ambulance responses.  I have created clusters for locations they respond from and created time bins to divide the time into manageable bins.   I then grouped the data by cluster and then by bin and have the number of incident per cluster per bin aggregated into a column as well.   I need to fill in zeros for all the time bins where no incidents occurred in the incident count column. I have tried a nested for loop with an if else to make it work.  It runs too slowly and I am trying to find a way to switch to a nested list comprehension with the if else statements.

```
count_values = ers_bin_groupby['no_of_incidents'].values

vals = ers_unique
```

"ers_unique" is a list of all the unique time bins for each cluster

```
def fill_missing(count_values,vals):
smoothed_regions=[]
ind=0  # ind iterates over count_values only
for p in range(0,posts):
    smoothed_bins=[]
    for i in range(max(minute_bin_create_times)):
        if i in vals[p]:
            smoothed_bins.append(count_values[ind])
            ind+=1
        else:
            smoothed_bins.append(0)
    smoothed_regions.extend(smoothed_bins)
    print(p)
return smoothed_regions
```

This is my attempt at a list comprehension with if statement

```
def fill_missing2(count_values, vals):
   smoothed_regions = []
   ind = 0   #ind iterates over count_values only
   smoothed_regions =[[count_values[ind] ind+=1 if i in vals[p] else 0 
                  for i in range(max(minute_bin_create_times))] 
                  for p in range(0,posts)]
```

I can't figure out if I still need the "ind+=1" to make it progress through the count_values

Here is an example of the groupby data I am working with there are 20 posts and over 500,000 time bins

```
 post_area  time_bin    
 0             7      1
               59     1
               104    1
               113    1
               117    1
               147    1
               249    1
               255    1
```

This is an example of the ers_unique list
[[7, 59, 104, 113, 117, 147, 249, 255, 277, 283, 292, 310, 312, 358, 393, 406, 480, 537, 550, 553, 622,

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the `ind += 1` issue, note that `smoothed_regions.extend(smoothed_bins)` means that you return a flat list, not a list of `smoothed_bins` (as in your attempt).

Without a sample input/output, I can't test the code below, but I hope it's ok.

First, replace indices by iterations:

```
def fill_missing(count_values,vals):
    smoothed_regions=[]
    count_it = iter(count_values) # iterates over count_values only
    for val in vals: # I assume that posts == len(vals)
        smoothed_bins=[]
        for i in range(max(minute_bin_create_times)):
            if i in val:
                smoothed_bins.append(next(count_it))
            else:
                smoothed_bins.append(0)
        smoothed_regions.extend(smoothed_bins)
    return smoothed_regions
```

Then, replace the `if ... append... else... append ...` part with a `append(... if ... else ...)`, that is: use an expression instead of a statement:

```
def fill_missing(count_values,vals):
    smoothed_regions=[]
    count_it = iter(count_values) # iterates over count_values only
    for val in vals:
        smoothed_bins=[]
        for i in range(max(minute_bin_create_times)):
            smoothed_bins.append(next(count_it) if i in val else 0)
        smoothed_regions.extend(smoothed_bins)
    return smoothed_regions
```

Now, you can create a first list comprehension:

```
def fill_missing(count_values,vals):
    smoothed_regions=[]
    count_it = iter(count_values) # iterates over count_values only
    for val in vals[:posts]: # posts == len(vals)??
        smoothed_bins=[next(count_it) if i in val else 0 
                       for i in range(max(minute_bin_create_times))]
        smoothed_regions.extend(smoothed_bins)
    return smoothed_regions
```

Then, you need to build a list of all the smoothed binds and to flatten it (`extend`). 
Actually, a generator seem (to me) more adapted than a list :

```
def fill_missing(count_values,vals):
    count_it = iter(count_values) # iterates over count_values only
    all_smoothed_bins = ([next(count_it) if i in val else 0 
                   for i in range(max(minute_bin_create_times))] for val in vals[:posts])
    smoothed_regions = [v for smoothed_bins in all_smoothed_bins for v in smoothed_bins]
    return smoothed_regions
```

You can inline the last three lines if you want:

```
def fill_missing(count_values,vals):
    count_it = iter(count_values) # iterates over count_values only
    return [v
        for smoothed_bins in (
                [next(count_it) if i in val else 0 
                 for i in range(max(minute_bin_create_times))]
             for val in vals[:posts]
        )
        for v in smoothed_bins]
```